# Is WooCommerce order key unique?

Tags: wordpress

I want an unique order ticket number. Can I use the `wc_order_...` for this?

For example: `wc_order_VyAs1YRTMcCE0`

```php
$unique_key = $order->get_order_key();
$unique_key = explode("_", $unique_key);
$unique_key = isset($unique_key[2]) ? $unique_key[2] : false;
```

> I do it for outside coupon code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a unique order ticket number then you can user order ID that is unique, each order have different order ID.

`$unique_key = 'wc_order'. $order->get_id();`